# how to call a function under ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using angularjs 1 and node js for my project.

Here I am displaying products using ng-repeat.Each product I have an option to share in social networks. I need to get the share count of each so I need to call a function for getting the same.
I have tried to call function ng-init but for all products its taking the last product count

Here is my sample code

```
     <div ng-repeat="(key,popc) in product" class="courses-outer-div">       
          <div class="courses-text-div">
          <div class="course-title-div">
          {{popc.Title}}
          </div><br />
          <span class="ash-txt-sml">{{popc.ListFee|currency:"₹":0}}</span><br/>

<div class="common-left pad-top-10"><span class="blue-txt">Share</span><br />
<a target="_blank"  href="http://facebook.com/sharer.php?u=url&i=imagurl" target="_blank">
<img src="images/share-fb.png" width="24" height="23" alt="" /></a>
<div ng-init="getfbshare(popc.id)">{{fbcount}}</div>
</div>
</div></div>
```

Controller.js

```
$scope.getfbshare = function(id)
    {       
        $http.get('/api/fbcount'+id).then(function(response)
        {
            alert("f"+response.data.share.share_count)
            $scope.fbcount = response.data.share.share_count;           
        });
    };
```

alert is showing correct value.

Because of `ng-repeat` `$scope.fbcount` is taking the last value.

Please help me to find out the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `getfbshare` method sets a fixed value on the scope (`$scope.fbcount`), which will be overwritten by any subsequent calls to the function.

Instead of passing `popc.id` to your function, you can pass the entire `popc` object, then, in the response, you can modify the object, like so:

```
$scope.getfbshare = function(popc)
{       
    $http.get('/api/fbcount'+popc.id).then(function(response)
    {
        popc.fbcount = response.data.share.share_count;           
    });
};
```

Then, in your view:

```
<div ng-init="getfbshare(popc)">{{popc.fbcount}}</div>
```

Ideally you would call that method at a different part of your app lifecycle than with `ng-init`.